# Question on cosmological parameters and slow-roll potential

Tags: cosmology, cosmological-inflation, cosmic-microwave-background

Given a slow-roll potential $V (\phi)$, how do the cosmological parameters (see e.g. the Dodelson book on Cosmology, section 8.7) relate to this potential? I'm a bit confused how parameters such as primordial tilt and tensor modes relate to this potential.

Also, is this all just measured from looking at the CMB?